# Error in Integration Studio when calling endpoint that returns a lot of data

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I am trying to call a rest api that returns a maximum of 1000 data in wso2 integration studio and list its results in the script mediator. It does not work when the limit parameter is set to a value close to 1000. I can fetch 500 pieces of data. But I can't fetch more. How can I get this to work when there is too much data?

The error I got:

```
The script engine returned an Exception executing the external js script : null function mediate java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: out of range index
```

Here is my sample work:

```
<resource methods="GET" url-mapping="/GetTotalBuildingCountAndArea">
        <inSequence>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost/entities?type=Building&amp;limit=800">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <script language="js"><![CDATA[
            
            var buildings = mc.getPayloadJSON();
            mc.setPayloadJSON(JSON.stringify(buildings));
            
            ]]></script>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" 
               value="application/json"/>
            <jsontransform description="Json Convert">
                <property name="synapse.commons.json.output.autoPrimitive" value="true"/>
                <property name="synapse.commons.enableXmlNullForEmptyElement" 
             value="false"/>
            </jsontransform>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of `Script Mediator`. The documentation has this to say.

> The Micro Integrator uses Rhino engine to execute JavaScripts. Rhino
> engine converts the script to a method inside a Java class. Therefore,
> when processing large JSON data volumes, the code length must be less
> than 65536 characters, since the Script mediator converts the payload
> into a Java object. However, you can use the following alternative
> options to process large JSON data volumes.
>
> - Achieve the same functionality via a Class mediator .
> - If the original message consists of repetitive sections, you can use the Iterate mediator to generate a relatively small payload using
>   those repetitive sections. This will then allow you to use the Script
>   mediator.
> - The Script Mediator supports using Nashorn to execute JavaScripts, in addition to its default Rhino engine.

It's best to handle this in such a way you altogether avoid the issue. But you can try the third option mentioned above as well. In the Script mediator try changing the language to `nashornJS`.

```
<script language="nashornJS">
.
.
.
```